# How to get same result as uniform_real_distribution<double> r(numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), numeric_limits<double>::max())

Tags: c++

Sorry, my English is not native.

`std::uniform_real_distribution` constructor has parameter A and B.
A is lower limit number, and B is upper limit number.
but these parameters must be `B - A <= numeric_limits<double>::max()`.

So, we can't write following code.

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urand(std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
```

I want to get uniform random number [std::numeric_limits::lowest(), std::numeric_limits::max()].

How to get such random number?

Comment: Dunno if it would actually be a uniform distribution, but you could try using `std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t>` and copying the bits to a `double`. Probably would need tweaking to avoid NaN, infinities and denormal values. Even if it's uniform to begin with, such tweaking might make it non-uniform. If there's a subset of bits that you can always set randomly to achieve the full range with valid values, you could drive those the same way with a smaller range and then copy them into the correct positions in the double.

Comment: Given how non-uniform the floats/doubles are, I'm not even sure what you mean by a uniform random value across the whole range.

Comment: @Mat something similar to `std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urand(0, std::numeric_limits<double>::max())`, but with negative numbers too. It's exceedingly likely to be a huge number (or a negative huge number)

Comment: @Caleth I suppose Mat refers to eg the difference between the interval `[0...10]` and `10^200 + [0....10]` in the last interval all numbers are the same `double` value. But uniform distribution would have equal prob in each of them

Comment: @Mat _I'm not sure what you mean by a uniform random value across the whole range._  It means the values generated are [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution). If you divide the range into `n` buckets of equal width, where `width = max / n - lowest / n`, then the probability that a given random variate falls in any given bucket is `1/n`. The fact that the _density_ of floating point values varies from bucket to bucket means that the values in low density buckets are more likely to be "reused" than values in high density buckets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get uniform random number [std::numeric_limits::lowest(), std::numeric_limits::max()].
>
> How to get such random number?

Splitting the interval in half is a relatively straightforward workaround. It works, however, only when `lowest == -max`, i.e., when the following `static_assert` succeeds:

```cpp
static constexpr double lowest{ std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() };
static constexpr double max{ std::numeric_limits<double>::max() };
static_assert(lowest == -max);
```

I chose these two half-open intervals: `[lowest, zero)` and `[zero, max)`. They dovetail nicely to cover the range `[lowest, max)`, which is precisely the range that would have been generated by the distribution `urand` in the OP (if only it worked!). They do not, however, match the closed interval `[lowest, max]` mentioned in the quoted passage above. (See my original answer below for a discussion of closed intervals.)

If a single interval is used, for example, `[zero, max)`, with a random draw selecting the sign (positive or negative), then a tiny bias will be introduced, because the value `zero` will appear twice as often as it should.

Here are the distributions that correspond to the two intervals I chose. One generates negative values; the other, non-negative (i.e., zero and positive).

```cpp
thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> neg{ lowest, zero };
thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> pos{ zero, max };
```

In the program below, function `random_double` returns a random number on the interval `[lowest, max)`. It draws a random boolean to decide which of the two distributions above, `pos` or `neg`, to use.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

std::mt19937& rng() {
    thread_local std::mt19937 engine{ std::random_device{}() };
    return engine;
}
bool random_bool() {
    thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<int> b{ 0, 1 };
    return b(rng());
}
double random_double() {
    static constexpr double zero{};
    static constexpr double lowest{ std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest() };
    static constexpr double max{ std::numeric_limits<double>::max() };
    static_assert(lowest == -max);
    thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> neg{ lowest, zero };
    thread_local std::uniform_real_distribution<double> pos{ zero, max };
    return random_bool() ? neg(rng()) : pos(rng());
}
int main()
{
    for (int i{ 7 }; i--;) {
        for (int j{ 3 }; j--;)
            std::cout << std::format("{:< 24.16} ", random_double());
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Note: In programs with just a single thread, you can replace `thread_local` with `static`.

##### Output

This is an unusual range. Because the numbers are *uniformly distributed*, you expect roughly half of them to be larger in absolute magnitude than `max / 2`. So, half will be larger than `1.79e+308` divided by 2, which is about `0.9e+308`.

That explains why the numbers are so large in the output below.

```
 1.426308249157231e+308  -1.249915247059728e+308   3.723649003787207e+307
 3.423686404333991e+306  -2.243956117081979e+307  -1.738125325637238e+308
-9.352178613691052e+307   3.428297653605854e+307  -1.192096021499717e+308
-1.00421692536256e+308   -8.43281030741466e+305    1.334612069614259e+307
 1.681506226783734e+308  -4.664959466337901e+307  -1.638422082313489e+308
 1.347838686386327e+308  -1.455767255755665e+308  -6.465783494768483e+307
 1.665612655589335e+308   7.579284504422257e+306  -6.931380571369055e+307
```

##### Real Distributions & Closed Intervals

Thanks to @Quimby for pointing out that I misread the OP.

> OP is not asking about B's inclusivity but how to overcome the limitation on the size of the range - that b-a must be representable as double. – Quimby

What follows is my original answer. It is what triggered Quimby's remark. Although it is irrelevant to the original question, for the time being, I will leave it here. Otherwise, there will be no way to make sense out of Quimby's comment. More importantly, the information may be of interest to some readers.

*Original answer:*

`std::uniform_real_distribution` returns a random value on the half-open interval [a, b), where `a` and `b` are the parameters from the distribution.

For example, the following distribution can return `-42.0`, but should never return `42.0`. Any value below `42.0` can be returned (so long as it is greater than or equal to `a`), but not `42.0` itself.

```cpp
double a = -42.0;
double b = 42.0;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urand{ a, b };
```

In theory, you could instantiate the distribution with `std::next_after` to return values on the closed interval [a, b].

```cpp
double a = -42.0;
double b = 42.0;
double bb = std::nextafter(b, std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urand{ a, bb };
```

This distribution returns values on the half-open interval [a, bb), which is effectively the same as the closed interval [a, b]. Unfortunately, however, [CppReference reports](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution#Notes) that this sometimes fails, due to rounding errors in the computation:

> It is difficult to create a distribution over the closed interval [a,b] from this distribution. Using `std::nextafter(b, std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max())` as the second parameter does not always work due to rounding error.

Even if this did work reliably, you could not use it when `b == std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`. Obviously, there is no value that is the "next_after" b in this case.

Ironically, the same [CppReference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution#Notes) explains that you may end up getting values on the closed interval [a, b], even when you want them on the half-open interval [a, b).

> Most existing implementations have a bug where they may occasionally return b (GCC #63176 LLVM #18767 MSVC STL #1074). This was originally only thought to happen when RealType is float and when LWG issue 2524 is present, but it has since been shown that neither is required to trigger the bug.

The conclusion is that `std::uniform_real_distribution` cannot reliably return values on a closed range.

Are there alternatives that use software from some other library? Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to that.

Is it critical that `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` appear in the output? If it is not crucial to your application, I would just live with whatever `urand` is giving you. The interval might be closed; or it might be half-open. Either way, it includes every other possible value in the range.

Comment: OP is not asking about `B`'s inclusivity but how to overcome the limitation on the size of the range - that `b-a` must be representable as `double`.

Answer (score 3):

If `std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()` is equal to `-std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`, you can uniformly pick in either the range `[0, std::numeric_limits<double>::max())` or `[std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), 0)`, and pick a  uniform boolean to choose which. Unfortunately this is a half-open interval, not a closed interval as you asked for.

```
class widened_uniform_real_distribution {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> neg{ std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(), 0 };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> pos{ 0, std::numeric_limits<double>::max() };
    std::bernoulli_distribution sign;
public:
    template<typename Generator>
    double operator()(Generator& g) {
        return sign(g) ? neg(g) : pos(g);
    }
    // all the other RandomNumberDistribution stuff
};
```

This isn't strictly portable, because it assumes things about the representation of `double`. The very common IEEE-754 binary64 representation has this property.

Comment: Is result of `double widened_uniform_real_distribution::operator()` uniformed distribution? I think plus signed and minus signed real number is generated with a probability of one in two.

Comment: @jsuzu That's why I said it requires lowest == -max. Each half of the range is equally big, and is picked with equal probability

Comment: There is a close probability that positive and negative values will be obtained alternately. Wouldn't that be considered uniform?

Comment: @jsuzu what do you mean alternately? [Here is an example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad2c359cd2dd1af4) of values produced. "I think plus signed and minus signed real number is generated with a probability of one in two" That's what you asked for.

Comment: _If a single interval is used, for example, [zero, max), with a random draw selecting the sign (positive or negative), then a tiny bias will be introduced, because the value zero will appear twice as often as it should._ Looks like you edited your answer after reading this in mine. No sweat. I wouldn't mind, however, an acknowledgement or up-vote!